# Why doesn't peer send handshake message in response to the handshake message I send?

Tags: python-3.x, bittorrent, python-3.5, handshake

I've started writing my own BitTorrent client in Python 3 recently. And all was perfect until I faced the following issue:
Instead of a response handshake when I send a formatted handshake message to one of the peers, I do not get anything (`b''` when buff is not decoded). Here is the code:

```
handshakemsg = chr(19)+"BitTorrent protocol"+8*chr(0)+
        getinfohash()+"HAHA-0142421214125A-")
s.send(handshakemsg.encode())
print("Connection to peer accepted")
buff = s.recv(len(handshakemsg))
print(buff)
```

That's the proper way of sending handshake message I think, but the response doesn't look like the one described in the specification. I'm wondering why is that happening, and how can I avoid that?

Comment: Maybe because you spelt "protocol" wrong?

Comment: No that's not the reason, I did it to test what would happen if i send wrong handshake, but I forgot to change it here. Thanks for reminding me anyways

Comment: can you show the binary output? capture it with wireshark

Comment: Yea, of course.. Here you are: [Link to image](http://i.imgur.com/fks6Oqz.png?1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html#peer-protocol

> After the fixed headers come eight reserved bytes, which are all zero in all current implementations. If you wish to extend the protocol using these bytes, please coordinate with Bram Cohen to make sure all extensions are done compatibly.
>   **Next comes the *20 byte* sha1 hash** of the bencoded form of the info value from the metainfo file.

Yours is 40 (hex-encoded). Bittorrent is a binary protocol, not text.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the whole handshake message is sent to remote peer, so try to use `socket.sendall()` method.

change:

```
s.send(handshakemsg.encode())
```

to:

```
s.sendall(handshakemsg.encode())
```

Comment: In the current situation, the reason the handshake message wasn't read properly from the peer was because the handshake contained hex-encoded property instead of byte-encoded one, as mentioned in the approved answer.